# How to create link syntax in PHP

Tags: php, url, syntax

I have a button that calls te "$pageID" so that when you click on the button it will browse to the url, appending it with "pageID=#" ... I want to expand this to include "campaignID#"
however when I do this I get:

```
editPage.php?pageID=193%26campaignID%3D1&editPage=Edit
```

The Problem here is the %26 and %3D which need to be an Ampersand and an Eqals sign. I have tried using strip slashes :

```
<?php echo $pageID."\&campaignID\=".$campaignID; ?>
```

But that hasn't worked, so I tried using the %26 and %3D, with even more disasterous results.
Can someone help me with this syntax.

Thank you

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is the urldecode() function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: Freaky, no matter which way I try, either urlencode, rawurlencode, urldecode I get the same issue.

Comment: This question is completely misleading. What he wanted was adding a new `<input>` field inside a `<form>` element for the `campaignID` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `http_build_query()` for it:

```
echo 'editPage.php?' . http_build_query(array(
    'pageID' => $pageID,
    'campaignID' => 1,
    'editPage' => 'Edit',
));
```

This typically avoids applying the wrong encoding you might do manually.

Comment: Thanks for the array, but it's still returning 
`?pageID=pageID%3D193%26campaignID%3D1&editPage=Edit` in the URL :-S

Comment: Where is `$pageID` defined? What do you put inside there?

Answer (score 0):

Use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

```
"editPage.php?pageID=".urlencode($pageID)."&editPage=Edit"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pageID = "123";
$campaignID = "1";
echo "editPage.php?pageID=" .$pageID. "&campaignID=" .$campaignID. "&editPage=Edit";
```

result is

```
editPage.php?pageID=123&campaignID=1&editPage=Edit
```

Comment: The issue is not the numbering it is the "&" and "=" signs that keep changing to `%26` and `%3D` respectively.

Comment: can you parse your code here? or have you tried my code?

Answer (score 0):

Also, for the sake of spotting and clarifying your error. You need to use `&` and `=`, not `\&` and `\=`.

```
<?php echo $pageID . "&campaignID=" . $campaignID; ?>
```

Comment: Yes, sorry for the ambiguity. I used the `&` and `=` first, then tried escaping them, I have also tried urlencode in both string statement form and as vars, but to no avail

Comment: I manged to fix it in the call value:
`<div class="buttons">
                    <form name="editPage" action="editPage.php" method="GET"> 
      <input type="hidden" name="campaignID" value="<?php echo $campaignID ?>"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="pageID" value="<?php echo $pageID ?>"/>
                        <button type="submit" name="editPage" value="Edit" class="blue" >
                       <img src="images/edit.png" width="20" height="20"></button>
                     
                    </form>
                     </div>`